# Converting a dictionary of dataframes into a Pandas MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel

Using Pandas Panels it was possible to supply a dictionary of dataframes:

```
data = {'A': df_A,
        'B': df_B,
           etc... }
```

into `pandas.Panel(data)` to create a 3 dimensional dataframe representation of the data - and access it accordingly.

Now panels have been depreciated, the suggestion is to create a multi-index dataframe.

Since it seems unwise to use `pandas.Panel.to_frame` (If I already have a panel, I wouldn't need to change it) and excessive to add a repeated `key` column to each data frame and merge them, what is the currently approved method for converting a dictionary of data frames into a multi index one?

---

Comment: How working `df = pd.concat(data)` ?

Comment: Which forms a 2D dictionary of duplicated indexes. There is no way to pull out an individal item as you would with a panel (e.g. `panel['A' , : , : ] `)

Comment: And yes you can do `pd.concat(data).set_index(['old_index','dict_key_column'])` and reference it using `.loc[['A','D'],:]` but that involves creating a column containing each dictionary key for every dataframe - which is what am trying to avoid (as per the question)